# Setting the value of a hidden field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am attempting to run a create.js.erb file when a user creates a record inside a RoR app.

Here is the jquery:

```
$('input[id=bizid]').val("<%= @branch.business_id %>");
$('input[id=braid]').val("<%= @branch.id %>");
```

Here is the view:

```
<input style="display:none;" id="bizid" name="bizid" value="" />
<input style="display:none;" id="braid" name="braid" value="" />
```

I have also tried this:

```
$('#bizid').val("<%= @branch.business_id %>");
$('#braid').val("<%= @branch.id %>");

<input type="hidden" id="bizid" name="bizid" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="braid" name="braid" value="">
```

I know that the machinery is working because I use @branch to update another text input field in the same form, without any issue. Also, I checked the DB and the above values for @branch do exist, and should be ready to pass.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
alert("<%= @branch.business_id %>");
alert("<%= @branch.id %>");
```

The above (placed in create.js.erb) results in the correct id #s in two alert dialogs.

Comment: Have you tried hard coding it:  `$('#bizid').val('my id');` to see if that works?

Comment: are you wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){/*yourcode*/});`

Comment: @Diodeus his example has unique id's.

Comment: Is this a simplified version of your code? Because if not, why use JS at all?

Comment: Have you tried using text fields (for these fields) to see what happens?

Comment: I would check if branch id and branch business id is returning anything at all, if so then worry about the jquery. I know you checked them in the Db but have you tried outputting it somewhere to make sure it is not returning empty string?

Comment: @Huangism I am definitely getting the results. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#bizid').val("<%= @branch.business_id %>");
$('#bizid').val("<%= @branch.id %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is in the document ready function:

```
$(function(){

   /** YOUR CODE **/

});
```

Also make sure that all of you id's are **unique**.

Comment: Thanks Neal. I tried this, but unfortunately still no luck. See my edit above. The data is there.